# Json path to extract based on particular value

Tags: scala, gatling

I have scenario in gatling where i need to extract particular JSON value. For eg: I want to extract author of book title "Sayings of the Century". I am using following `Jsonpath $..book[?(@.title eq 'Sayings of the Century')]`. But its not returning me anything. Can you tell me how to achieve this.

```
{ "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you dont make it an object and search on the object? if you are using GUI try firebug to test your path

Comment: Since its gatling test case, I cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is `==`, not `eq`

You can test you expression with online tools such as http://ashphy.com/JSONPathOnlineEvaluator

Answer (score 0):

It's different between java and scala. You should show clearly the type of jsonPath in scala.

For example, in java the code is:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonString, "$.message_metadata.event_type");
```

but in scala it is:

```
JsonPath.read\[String\](jsonString, "$.message_metadata.event_type")
```

If your result type is JSONArray, the code is like:

`JsonPath.read\[JSONArray\](jsonString, "$.message_metadata.event_type")`

Hope this can help you.